# ERROR:TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Tags: angular

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:6)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:36055)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35067)
    at callViewAction (core.js:35433)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:35390)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35068)
    at callViewAction (core.js:35433)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:35361)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35074)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:36407)
```

My code was working fine..Accidentally I happened to have deleted the user but recreated the profile..since then the above error is showing while trying to log in with the user..Attached is the component.ts..Can I get some help?

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from './user.service';
import {throwError} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public users: any;
  /**
   * An object representing the user for the login form
   */
  public user: any;

  constructor(public _userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    };
  }

  login() {
    this._userService.login({'username': this.user.username, 'password': this.user.password});
  }

  refreshToken() {
    this._userService.refreshToken();
  }

  logout() {
    this._userService.logout();
  }

  getUsers() {
    this.users = this._userService.getUsers();
   }
}
```

This is the template..Though I havent altered anything in this file..
app.component.html

```
<h2>Log In</h2>
<div class="row" *ngIf="!_userService.token">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label>Username:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="login-username" [(ngModel)]="user.username">
    <span *ngFor="let error of _userService.errors.username"><br/>{{ error }}</span></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label>Password:</label><br />
    <input type="password" name="login-password" [(ngModel)]="user.password">
    <span *ngFor="let error of _userService.errors.password"><br/>{{ error }}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <button (click)="login()" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>&nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <span *ngFor="let error of _userService.errors.non_field_errors">{{ error }}<br /></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" *ngIf="_userService.token">
  <div class="col-sm-12">You are logged in as {{ _userService.username }}.<br />
    Token Expires: {{ _userService.token_expires }}<br />
    <button (click)="refreshToken()" class="btn btn-primary">Refresh Token</button>&nbsp;
    <button (click)="getUsers()" class="btn btn-primary">Get Users</button>
    <button (click)="logout()" class="btn btn-primary">Log Out</button>&nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

user.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  // http options used for making API calls
  private httpOptions: any;

  // the actual JWT token
  public token: string;

  // the token expiration date
  public token_expires: Date;

  // the username of the logged in user
  public username: string;

  // user array
  public userList: any = [];

  // error messages received from the login attempt
  public errors: any = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    };
  }

  // Uses http.post() to get an auth token from djangorestframework-jwt endpoint
  public login(user) {
    this.http.post('/api-token-auth/', JSON.stringify(user), this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('login success', data);
        this.updateData(data['token']);
        localStorage.setItem('token', data['token']);
      },
      err => {
        this.errors = err['error'];
      }
    );
  }

  /**
   * Refreshes the JWT token, to extend the time the user is logged in
   */
  public refreshToken() {
    this.http.post('/api-token-refresh/', JSON.stringify({token: this.token}), this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('refresh success', data);
        this.updateData(data['token']);
        localStorage.setItem('token', data['token']);
      },
      err => {
        console.error('refresh error', err);
        this.errors = err['error'];
      }
    );
  }

  public getUsers() {
    this.http.get('/api-users/', {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('token')
      })
    }).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.userList = data['token'];
      },
      err => {
        console.error('authorization error', err);
        this.errors = err['error'];
      }
    );
  }

  public logout() {
    this.token = null;
    this.token_expires = null;
    this.username = null;
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }

  private updateData(token) {
    this.token = token;
    this.errors = [];

    // decode the token to read the username and expiration timestamp
    const token_parts = this.token.split(/\./);
    const token_decoded = JSON.parse(window.atob(token_parts[1]));
    this.token_expires = new Date(token_decoded.exp * 1000);
    this.username = token_decoded.username;
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you share your .html file?

Comment: looks like you missed out something in your ````app.component.html````. Please share this file so we can help you better

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

object user getting undefined and you are using undefined.username. Use
{{user?.username}}

Comment: Not working..instead replacing "user.username" by  {{user?.username}} in ngmodel is giving error

Answer (score 0):

Your `user` variable is undefined initially. Try setting `user` to an empty object initially.

```
public user: any = {};
```

You can also use @Syam's answer but you do not need to add the interpolation. Simply change your `ngModel` in your html to `[(ngModel)]="user?.username"`

**Edit**: I just noticed the next line in your code. In your `ngFor`, you have`let error of _userService.errors.username`. You will not be able to access `_userService` in your html since you have declared it as `private`. In your component's contructor, change `private _userService: UserService` to `public _userService: UserService` Also make sure `errors` exists in `UserService`.

Comment: even setting user as an empty object is not working..Is this problem occurring because it is unable to fetch the user?

Comment: can you also post the code of your ````UserService````? since the issue seems to be coming from there.